# Binary grep on Linux?

Tags: linux, binary, grep

Say I have generated the following binary file:

```
# generate file:
python -c 'import sys;[sys.stdout.write(chr(i)) for i in (0,0,0,0,2,4,6,8,0,1,3,0,5,20)]' > mydata.bin

# get file size in bytes
stat -c '%s' mydata.bin

# 14
```

And say, I want to find the locations of all zeroes (`0x00`), using a grep-like syntax.

The best I can do so far is:

```
$ hexdump -v -e "1/1 \" %02x\n\"" mydata.bin | grep -n '00'

1: 00
2: 00
3: 00
4: 00
9: 00
12: 00
```

However, this implicitly converts each byte in the original binary file into a multi-byte ASCII representation, on which `grep` operates; not exactly the prime example of optimization :)

Is there something like a binary `grep` for Linux? Possibly, also, something that would support a regular expression-like syntax, but also for byte "characters" - that is, I could write something like '`a(\x00*)b`' and match 'zero or more' occurrences of byte 0 between bytes 'a' (97) and 'b' (98)?

EDIT: The context is that I'm working on a driver, where I capture 8-bit data; something goes wrong in the data, which can be kilobytes up to megabytes, and I'd like to check for particular signatures and where they occur. (*so far, I'm working with kilobyte snippets, so optimization is not that important - but if I start getting some errors in megabyte long captures, and I need to analyze those, my guess is I would like something more optimized :) . And especially, I'd like something where I can "grep" for a byte as a character - `hexdump` forces me to search strings per byte*)

EDIT2: same question, different forum :) [grepping through a binary file for a sequence of bytes](http://www.linuxquestions.org/questions/linux-software-2/grepping-through-a-binary-file-for-a-sequence-of-bytes-717503/)

EDIT3: Thanks to the answer by @tchrist, here is also an example with 'grepping' and matching, and displaying results (*although not quite the same question as OP*):

```
$ perl -ln0777e 'print unpack("H*",$1), "\n", pos() while /(.....\0\0\0\xCC\0\0\0.....)/g' /path/to/myfile.bin

ca000000cb000000cc000000cd000000ce     # Matched data (hex)
66357                                  # Offset (dec)
```

To have the matched data be grouped as one byte (two hex characters) each, then "H2 H2 H2 ..." needs to be specified for as many bytes are there in the matched string; as my match '`.....\0\0\0\xCC\0\0\0.....`' covers 17 bytes, I can write '`"H2"x17`' in Perl. Each of these "H2" will return a separate variable (as in a list), so `join` also needs to be used to add spaces between them - eventually:

```
$ perl -ln0777e 'print join(" ", unpack("H2 "x17,$1)), "\n", pos() while /(.....\0\0\0\xCC\0\0\0.....)/g' /path/to/myfile.bin

ca 00 00 00 cb 00 00 00 cc 00 00 00 cd 00 00 00 ce
66357
```

Well.. indeed Perl is very nice 'binary grepping' facility, I must admit :) As long as one learns the syntax properly :)

Comment: Why do you care about optimization? This question might be easier to answer if you can provide some more context on what you are trying to do.

Comment: @David Dean: thanks for raising the issue! I have added an edit, hope it clarifies! @tchrist - thanks for that, had no idea I could use Perl for it :) I barely found the syntax to persuade Python to generate byte-level files :) (_and I used it here, simply because I wanted to show the exact file contents, and the behavior I'm looking for_)

Comment: @sdaau: I’ve updated my answer for you.  It should be easier to understand now.

Comment: @sdaau: You can adapt my technique in Perl to search for sequences of bytes, too. `perl -ln0777e 'print pos() while /illegal/g' /usr/bin/awk` will tell you all the offsets for the string `illegal`.  Replace with `/\x1A\0\x43\x41/` for just those four bytes.  Etc.  You already **have** a binary grepper!

Comment: @tchrist - thanks for the update - a binary grepper indeed :) Certainly a good incentive for me to learn more Perl.. Cheers!

Comment: Tried the one-liners on a 250 GB file and perl said "Out of memory!". Can Perl also be used for files that don't fit into memory?

Answer (score 14, accepted):

### One-Liner Input

Here’s the shorter one-liner version:

```
% perl -ln0e 'print tell' < inputfile
```

And here's a slightly longer one-liner:

```
% perl -e '($/,$\) = ("\0","\n"); print tell while <STDIN>' < inputfile
```

The way to connect those two one-liners is by uncompiling the first one’s program:

```
% perl -MO=Deparse,-p -ln0e 'print tell'
BEGIN { $/ = "\000"; $\ = "\n"; }
LINE: while (defined(($_ = <ARGV>))) {
    chomp($_);
    print(tell);
}
```

### Programmed Input

If you want to put that in a file instead of a calling it from the command line, here’s a somewhat  more explicit version:

```
#!/usr/bin/env perl

use English qw[ -no_match_vars ];

$RS  = "\0";    # input  separator for readline, chomp
$ORS = "\n";    # output separator for print

while (<STDIN>) {
    print tell();
}
```

And here’s the really long version:

```
#!/usr/bin/env perl

use strict;
use autodie;  # for perl5.10 or better
use warnings qw[ FATAL all  ];

use IO::Handle;

IO::Handle->input_record_separator("\0");
IO::Handle->output_record_separator("\n");

binmode(STDIN);   # just in case

while (my $null_terminated = readline(STDIN)) {
    # this just *past* the null we just read:
    my $seek_offset = tell(STDIN);
    print STDOUT $seek_offset;  

}

close(STDIN);
close(STDOUT);
```

### One-Liner Output

BTW, to create the test input file, I didn’t use your big, long   Python script; I just used this simple  Perl one-liner:

```
% perl -e 'print 0.0.0.0.2.4.6.8.0.1.3.0.5.20' > inputfile
```

You’ll find that Perl often winds up being 2-3 times shorter than Python to do the same job.  And you don’t have to compromise on clarity; what could be simpler that the one-liner above?

### Programmed Output

I know, I know.  If you don’t already know the language, this might be clearer:

```
#!/usr/bin/env perl
@values = (
    0,  0,  0,  0,  2,
    4,  6,  8,  0,  1,
    3,  0,  5, 20,
);
print pack("C*", @values);
```

although this works, too:

```
print chr for @values;
```

as does

```
print map { chr } @values;
```

Although for those who like everything all rigorous and careful and all, this might be more what you would see:

```
#!/usr/bin/env perl

use strict;
use warnings qw[ FATAL all ];
use autodie;

binmode(STDOUT);

my @octet_list = (
    0,  0,  0,  0,  2,
    4,  6,  8,  0,  1,
    3,  0,  5, 20,
);

my $binary = pack("C*", @octet_list);
print STDOUT $binary;

close(STDOUT);
```

### TMTOWTDI

Perl supports more than one way to do things so that you can pick the one that you’re most comfortable with.  If this were something I planned to check in as school or work project, I would certainly select the longer, more careful versions — or at least put a comment in the shell script if I were using the one-liners.

You can find documentation for Perl on your own system.  Just type

```
% man perl
% man perlrun
% man perlvar
% man perlfunc
```

etc at your shell prompt.  If you want pretty-ish versions on the web instead, get the manpages for [perl](http://perldoc.perl.org/perl.html), [perlrun](http://perldoc.perl.org/perlrun.html), [perlvar](http://perldoc.perl.org/perlvar.html), and [perlfunc](http://perldoc.perl.org/index-functions.html) from http://perldoc.perl.org.

Comment: Thanks for this - it works just fine!! Except I have no idea why :) Would you mind adding a link to a reference to the syntax used here? Not really a Perl person myself, and I don't think searching will return much on a query like "`perl ($/,$\) syntax`" :)

Comment: Wow, thanks @tchrist! I'm changing the accepted answer to this, simply because it opened my eyes to applicability of Perl to 'binary grepping' :) There's still a lot to go through - but now, at least I can consult [perlvar](http://perldoc.perl.org/perlvar.html) to find that `$/` refers to "slurp mode" :) Cheers!

Comment: How would one one apply this to arbitrary binary strings?  I tried your `perl -ln0777e 'print pos() while /illegal/g' /usr/bin/awk` approach to find lost content in a raw disk device file, but perl barfed at me with "Out of memory" partway through.

Answer (score 56):

This seems to work for me:

```
grep --only-matching --byte-offset --binary --text --perl-regexp "<\x-hex pattern>" <file>
```

Short form:

```
grep -obUaP "<\x-hex pattern>" <file>
```

Example:

```
grep -obUaP "\x01\x02" /bin/grep
```

Output ([Cygwin](http://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Cygwin) binary):

```
153: <\x01\x02>
33210: <\x01\x02>
53453: <\x01\x02>
```

So you can grep this again to extract offsets. But don't forget to use binary mode again.

Comment: A bit late, but thanks for this - an example with `grep` doing binary with offsets was really needed; cheers!

Comment: This doesn't seem to work on binary characters greater than 0x7f for me.  Grep just doesn't match.

Comment: @fuzzyTew I've managed to make it work by setting `LANG=C` (previously LANG=pt_BR.UTF-8 and perhaps grep was trying to interpret unicode characters out of my byte stream).

Comment: @Fr0sT Why do you added --text --perl-regexp ? If you are scanning a binary file with a fixed byte sequence you don't need either. Do you?

Comment: @EnzoR `--text` changes output mode. Just try with it and without and see the difference

Comment: @Fr0sT From the manual page I read: "-a, --text: Process a binary file as if it were text; this is equivalent to the --binary-files=text option."

Comment: @EnzoR this option is in `Output control` section so... again, just try with it and without and see the difference. Or ask grep devs why they have created such an unclear description

Comment: @Fr0sT Nope. It's in the "*File and Directory Selection*" section. https://www.gnu.org/software/grep/manual/grep.html

Comment: @EnzoR yep maybe. I have Cygwin's grep 2.6.3 only that has this option where I said. Anyway I just found options that do the job. Investigating why they are called as they are called is out of my interest  ¯\_(ツ)_/¯

Comment: Doesn't work for all binary strings, suggest using `ack` which is written in python (ergo fully supports binary regex).

Comment: `printf "\xc3\x87\x71\xc7\x71" | grep -obUaP "\xc7\x71"` returns wrong results. fixed by `printf "\xc3\x87\x71\xc7\x71" | grep -obUaE $'\xc7\x71'`

Comment: very wrong... for example `\xff\x00\x00` sequence is never found.

Answer (score 19):

Someone else appears to have been similarly frustrated and wrote their own tool to do it (or at least something similar): [bgrep](https://github.com/tmbinc/bgrep).

Comment: Thanks much for that - it makes a lot of sense, I have no idea why did it not come up in my searches! :) Haven't tried it yet, but I'm pretty sure it will work for my needs !

Comment: bgrep works wonderfully, except when trying to search a large file (5Gb).

Comment: @Omniwombat Could it be you're running a 32-bit system? Might be a simple case of adding a compiler flag as expressed in this issue: https://github.com/tmbinc/bgrep/issues/12 — if not, developer would probably appreciate a bug report.

Answer (score 13):

The [bbe](http://sourceforge.net/projects/bbe-/) program is a [sed](http://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Sed)-like editor for binary files. See [documentation](http://htmlpreview.github.io/?https://github.com/hdorio/bbe/blob/master/doc/bbe.html).

Example with *bbe*:

```
bbe -b "/\x00\x00\xCC\x00\x00\x00/:17" -s -e "F d" -e "p h" -e "A \n" mydata.bin

11:x00 x00 xcc x00 x00 x00 xcd x00 x00 x00 xce
```

#### Explanation

```
-b search pattern between //. each 2 byte begin with \x (hexa notation).
   -b works like this /pattern/:length (in byte) after matched pattern
-s similar to 'grep -o' suppress unmatched output 
-e similar to 'sed -e' give commands
-e 'F d' display offsets before each result here: '11:'
-e 'p h' print results in hexadecimal notation
-e 'A \n' append end-of-line to each result
```

You can also pipe it to *sed* to have a cleaner output:

```
bbe -b "/\x00\x00\xCC\x00\x00\x00/:17" -s -e "F d" -e "p h" -e "A \n" mydata.bin | sed -e 's/x//g'

11:00 00 cc 00 00 00 cd 00 00 00 ce
```

> Your solution with *Perl* from your EDIT3 give me an 'Out of memory'
>   error with large files.
>
> The same problem goes with *bgrep*.
>
> The only downside to bbe is that I don't know how to print context that precedes a matched pattern.

Comment: Thanks for that, @Doud - `bbe` looks quite good; and many thanks for the quick examples! Cheers!

Comment: generating the search pattern with xxd: `cat needle.bin | dd status=none bs=512 count=1 skip=0 | xxd -p -c 1 | sed 's/^..$/\\x&/' | tr -d '\n'` - limitation of bbe: maximum size of needle.bin is 16385 bytes

Comment: @milahu, I think what you are trying to say is that the search pattern (-b parameter) has a 16k limit, which is true.

Comment: @milahu you may want to change `INPUT_BUFFER_LOW (16*1024)` from bbe.h to fit your needs.

Answer (score 9):

One way to solve your immediate problem using only grep is to create a file containing a single null byte.  After that, `grep -abo -f null_byte_file target_file` will produce the following output.

```
0:
1:
2:
3:
8:
11:
```

That is of course each byte offset as requested by "-b" followed by a null byte as requested by "-o"

I'd be the first to advocate perl, but in this case there's no need to bring in the extended family.

Comment: Thanks @Omniwombat, +1 for an interesting alternative!

Comment: This works great for me, even with weird binary characters and huge input data.  And it still uses the familiar, common, and pervasive `grep` tool !

Answer (score 1):

What about `grep -a`?  Not sure how it works on truly binary files but it works well on text files that the OS thinks is binary.

Comment: Hi @Chance, thanks for your comment! I have been using `grep -a` before, but to find text strings (in other words, bytes in ASCII range) - haven't had luck with finding sequences of null bytes, for example.. Also, not sure if one can persuade `grep` to output the byte offset of a match. Cheers!

Answer (score 0):

```
python3 -c "import sys;print(hex(sys.stdin.buffer.read().find(b'\x00\x00\xff')));"<file
```

the binary bytes 00 00 FF   can't be found with the other methods in this answers.

example:

```
python3 -c "import sys;print(hex(sys.stdin.buffer.read().find(b'\x00\x00\xff')));"< /bin/bash
0x0a
```