# Find the offset of data in a binary file

Tags: linux, shell

Is there a Linux command-line tool (like grep) that can take a binary file and a series of bytes and return the first index where these bytes appear in the file?

Comment: Possible duplicate: http://stackoverflow.com/questions/4180081/linux-binary-grep

Answer (score 2):

```
$ grep --only-matching --byte-offset --max-count=1 --text --perl-regexp "\xefa" pathtofile

22157929:ïa
```

Outputs offset in bytes (start with 0) along with found text, e.g. `\xefa` searchs for byte with hex code `xe` followed by char `a`, `--max-count` how many occurrences to find. Works on my Linux Mint.

Answer (score 0):

You can use `xxd` to create a hexdump of the binary files and search that.

Comment: Not exactly what I was looking for, but the comment by @Dan Fego did the job :-)