# How to dump part of binary file

Tags: linux, bash, terminal, dump

I have binary and want to extract part of it, starting from know byte string (i.e. FF D8 FF D0) and ending with known byte string (AF FF D9)

In the past I've used `dd` to cut part of binary file from beginning/ending but this command doesn't seem to support what I ask.

What tool on terminal can do this?

Answer (score 3, accepted):

In a single pipe:

```
xxd -c1 -p file |
  awk -v b="ffd8ffd0" -v e="aaffd9" '
    found == 1 {
      print $0
      str = str $0
      if (str == e) {found = 0; exit}
      if (length(str) == length(e)) str = substr(str, 3)}
    found == 0 {
      str = str $0
      if (str == b) {found = 1; print str; str = ""}
      if (length(str) == length(b)) str = substr(str, 3)}
    END{ exit found }' |
  xxd -r -p > new_file
test ${PIPESTATUS[1]} -eq 0 || rm new_file
```

The idea is to use `awk` between two `xxd` to select the part of the file that is needed.  Once the 1st pattern is found, `awk` prints the bytes until the 2nd pattern is found and exit.

The case where the 1st pattern is found but the 2nd is not must be taken into account.  It is done in the `END` part of the `awk` script, which return a non-zero exit status.  This is catch by `bash`'s `${PIPESTATUS[1]}` where I decided to delete the new file.

Note that en empty file also mean that nothing has been found.

Comment: Yet another mark reassignment - lOranger' solution fails if 2nd pattern can be found before the 1st - giving $len with negative sign. This solution searches after the 1st pattern match, so it doesn't have such problem, nor generates intermediate triple size file.

Comment: After testing this more, I found it without issues, but it's rather slow on larger files. Does anyone see a place for some optimisation, or this is the best one can get from xxd/awk?

Comment: Try the new `sed` version that I just post.  This one can be optimized replacing string concatenation and extraction with rotatory indexes in arrays, but it is less readable; and I do not want to do it if not needed ;-).

Answer (score 7):

Locate the start/end position, then extract the range.

```
$ xxd -g0 input.bin | grep -im1 FFD8FFD0  | awk -F: '{print $1}'
0000cb0
$ ^FFD8FFD0^AFFFD9^
0009590
$ dd ibs=1 count=$((0x9590-0xcb0+1)) skip=$((0xcb0)) if=input.bin of=output.bin
```

Comment: I found "..count=$((0x9590-0xcb0+2)) skip=$((0xcb0+1))..." to match exactly starting from "FFD8.." and ending to "AFFF..". Thank you for your nice procedure. Cheers

Comment: After couple of extractions I noticed that this is only approximate solution. +1, +2 all depend on content. For example `007d820: 74290068656c6c6f2e6a706700ffd8ff` gives 007d820 for both '74 29 00 68' and '00 ff d8 ff' so something slightly different has to be done

Comment: This *does not work*. If the pattern to match is split on two lines of `xxd` output it will never be found (by default `xxd -g0` group lines per 16 bytes). For a pattern of 4 bytes long the probability to have a split is 25%. Also, the `grep|awk` will print the address of the *beginning* of the line where the pattern occur, so a delta of up to line size can happen, you end up with more data than you really want.

Comment: @lOranger use `-c 160` option to reduce the probability.

Comment: We're not talking about *probability* here, but *certainty*! Even with 160 (the max is 256 for xxd), the probability is more than 2%, which is **huge**. If you automate this, you need a script that *works all the time*, not 98% of the times. See my answer below for a proposal that works all the time.

Answer (score 2):

This should work with standard tools (xxd, tr, grep, awk, dd). This correctly handles the "pattern split across line" issue, also look for the pattern only aligned at byte offset (not nibble).

```
file=<yourfile>
outfile=<youroutputfile>
startpattern="ff d8 ff d0"
endpattern="af ff d9"
xxd -g0 -c1 -ps ${file} | tr '\n' ' ' > ${file}.hex 
start=$((($(grep -bo "${startpattern}" ${file}.hex\
    | head -1 | awk -F: '{print $1}')-1)/3))
len=$((($(grep -bo "${endpattern}" ${file}.hex\
    | head -1 | awk -F: '{print $1}')-1)/3-${start}))
dd ibs=1 count=${len} skip=${start} if=${file} of=${outfile}
```

*Note:* The script above use a temporary file to prevent having the binary>hex conversion twice. A space/time trade-off is to pipe the result of `xxd` directly into the two `grep`. A one-liner is also possible, at the expense of clarity.

One could also use `tee` and named pipe to prevent having to store a temporary file and converting output twice, but I'm not sure it would be faster (xxd is fast) and is certainly more complex to write.

Comment: lOranger, I used -c64 to compensate a bit, and `cut` and `sed` to calculate correct address, but -c1 should be real solution. I'll mark your solution, but when I manage to make it work. First I needed to change place of `grep`'s pattern and filename to make grep work, but regardless I get `dd: invalid number` I imagine problem in start/len calculation/grammar. Also can't we exclude empty space and save 1/3 of output .hex file which would be double the input file size instead triple as it is now?

Comment: Sorry, there was a typo in the script: `grep` pattern should be *before* the filename. I also added a `| head -1` to cover the case where the pattern appears multiple times in the input, which can happen. Concerning your question, the space between hex bytes is necessary, otherwise you have the "nibble" issue (pattern is not aligned on byte boundaries).

Comment: I'm afraid it still doesn't work. I get input file as result. I used my -c64 script, and get expected dump, but I was unwilling to post it here as it was fragile on boundaries (better than provided, but still..)

Comment: Please note that you have to convert your hex pattern to *lowercase* (or add option `-i` in `grep`). I've just tested the script here with a big binary file and it works fine. Please print the value of ${start} and ${len} to debug (you can check that start and len > 0 to prevent cases where the pattern is not found in the input.

Comment: Just in case: http://pastebin.com/raw.php?i=hZ5UqAF9 Patterns are in lower case. It simply returns the input file as dump, so start and end position are 0 and input file length.

Comment: Well, I tested your script here and it works fine under a `bash` and `sh` script (provided I change the pattern to match some data in my input file). You have to check obviously that both patterns appears in the input. Which version of various tools are you using? Also please print `${start}` and `${len}` to check what's wrong. Please edit the .hex leftover file and manually check that the patterns are present, just in case...

Comment: Try it yourself with script from pastebin on this file: http://ge.tt/1EjaXGE/v/0 (160K)

Comment: let us [continue this discussion in chat](http://chat.stackoverflow.com/rooms/8261/discussion-between-loranger-and-theta)

Answer (score 1):

See [this link](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/4180081/linux-binary-grep) for a way to do binary grep. Once you have the start and end offset, you should be able with `dd` to get what you need.

Answer (score 1):

A variation on the `awk` solution that assumes that your binary file, once converted in hex with spaces, fits in memory:

```
xxd -c1 -p file |
  tr "\n" " " |
  sed -n -e 's/.*\(ff d8 ff d0.*aa ff d9\).*/\1/p' |
  xxd -r -p > new_file
```

Comment: WOW, this is so sweet and looks so easy. Couldn't be better than this. I'll leave mark on IOranger's answer as it is correct and answered earlier, but this is by far my favourite snippet

Comment: Too bad the quickest get the mark, not the shortest...  Anyway, it can still be optimized by removing the `tr`, replacing it inside `sed` by `-e '1h' -e '2,$H' -e '${x;s/\n/ /g}'` and modifying the above substitution to be performed only on last line.  Note that this solution does not work one huge binary files, as the file need to be put in memory in `sed`.  On huge files, use the `awk` solution.

Comment: Thanks. I tested this on 1GB laptop, and it was fine for 5MB file, but it made my system inaccessible on 50MB file. Is there maybe some general rule for determining "limit" file size based on available RAM, in your opinion?

Comment: A 50MB file means 150MB once decoded and once bytes are separated by spaces.  IT is not that much, but could cause `sed` to behave very slowly: a line of 150MB is a lot !  You could try the `-n` option to `sed` to remove buffering, but it could just worsen the problem.  It is difficult to give an opinion on the limit: I do not know about `sed` implementation.  The best is to do many tries.  Sorry not to be able to help more.

Comment: Thanks. You helped more then enough

Comment: The three sets of wildcards make `sed` do a lot of recursive searching, probably... I think that may be the reason that things slow down when the file gets big.

Answer (score 1):

Another solution in `sed`, but using less memory:

```
xxd -c1 -p file |
  sed -n -e '1{N;N;N}' -e '/ff\nd8\nff\nd0/{:begin;p;s/.*//;n;bbegin}' -e 'N;D' | 
  sed -n -e '1{N;N}' -e '/aa\nff\nd9/{p;Q1}' -e 'P;N;D' |
  xxd -r -p > new_file
test ${PIPESTATUS[2]} -eq 1 || rm new_file
```

The 1st `sed` prints from `ff d8 ff d0` till the end of file.  Note that you need as much `N` in `-e '1{N;N;N}'` as there is bytes in your 1st pattern **less one**.

The 2nd `sed` prints from the beginning of the file to `aa ff d9`.  Note again that you need as much `N` in `-e '1{N;N}'` as there is bytes in your 2nd pattern **less one**.

Again, a test is needed to check if the 2nd pattern is found, and delete the file if it is not.

Note that the `Q` command is a GNU extension to `sed`.  If you do not have it, you need to trash the rest of the file once the pattern is found (in a loop like the 1st `sed`, but not printing the file), and check after hex to binary conversion that the new_file end with the wright pattern.

Comment: I do have this GNU extension to sed, but can't make this script work for some reason

Comment: Sorry, typo in the 2nd `sed`: it should work if you replace `/aa\nff\nd9/` with `/af\nff\nd9/`.

Comment: I don't understand what difference that would make? Please try this sample: http://ge.tt/42cScKE/v/0?c (160K)

Comment: The link is not working :-(.  If you do not have any output, it means that those 2 patterns are not found.  You can debug the script running the 2 first commands and adding other after.  About the change, I think you are looking for data between `ff d8 ff d0` and `af ff d9`, but the script in my solution above is taking data between `ff d8 ff d0` and `aa ff d9`.

Comment: Sorry, link must have expired. I uploaded on other service, please try here: http://hotfile.com/dl/148193223/e90ab68/bin.dat.html Patterns are of course present in file, I checked multiple times

Comment: Ok, there was an error in the final test.  I corrected it.  The error was also in the awk version that I also corrected.

Answer (score 0):

You can use `binwalk` in order to do so. The tool will autodetect the files (an the offsets) in the input binary.

By using the `-e` flag, it will extract all the files in the same directory in which you are running the command.

It is installed by default in the newest distros but you can easily install the CLI tool with `sudo apt install binwalk`.

Here is an example of execution where I have hidden a zip file whose content is a text file called pass.txt. The whole thing is hidden in a .jgp image.
[image]
[image]

Read the manual for further information.