# How to search binary data in target directory?

Tags: search, full-text-search, binaryfiles, binary-search, binary-data

I tried *ag* and some other searcher, they only support searching normal text in binary files, but not support searching binary text in binary files.

I googled for "search binary text" and results all talking about "search text in binary file".

Any tool support searching like this `search_tool -bin "313233"`? (which is actually searching for files contain string "123")

Answer (score 1):

Let's build our own POSIX-compliant tool:

search_tool:

```
od -An -tx1 "$1" | tr -cd '[:xdigit:]' | grep -qF "$2"
```

This dumps the file in hexadecimal, removes non-hex digits, and searches the result.

```
$ chmod +x search_tool
$ ./search_tool somefile 313233
$ echo $?
0
```

`somefile` contains `123`.

---

You can use find(1) to run search_tool in any directory:

```
$ find java_playground ! -type d -a -exec search_tool {} 313233 \; -print
```

search_tool must be in locatable from `PATH`.

Comment: Few things: 1) Seeking recommendation for tools is grounds to close the question. 2) You said "any tool support" 3) You did not state non-functional requirements in your question. 4) That's entirely dependent upon the implementation.

5) This answer satisfies the functional requirements stated in the question.

Comment: Thanks, but I mean search in files in a directory, not in single file, like "ag", "grep"...

Comment: Given search_tool, I figured you would have your own mechanism to execute it for files in a directory. There's no guarantee other tools would provide that functionality either. Anyway, I provided a POSIX-compliant way to do so.

Answer (score 1):

Without knowing your requirements, this should suffice for most scenarios:

```
grep -robUaP "{YOUR_BINARY_SEQUENCE_HERE_IN_HEX_FORMAT}" {DIRECTORY_TO_SEARCH}
```

Example:

```
grep -robUaP "\x01\x02\x03" /bin
```

---

Based on: [Binary grep on Linux?](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/4180081/binary-grep-on-linux/4180510)

Answer (score 0):

I just wrote one using Golang, simple but works.

https://github.com/aj3423/bingrep